# VimWiki - Quick way to remove a llink without pluggins?

Tags: vim

Hitting Enter on a word will make it a link. I can't find any information for removing the link.
The best way I can think of is with the "surround" plugin to remove the brackets. Is there a way I can do this without a plugin?

Comment: Maybe you could show us how a "link" looks?

Comment: A [[Link]] looks like that, except you can 'click' it by hitting enter over the cursor.

Comment: You should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visually select the double brackets: `v2a]`.
2. Remove the brackets within the visual selection: `:'<,'>s/\%V[\[\]]//g`.

You can map it to something easy:

```
nnoremap <key> v2a]:keeppattern s/\%V[\[\]]//g<CR>
```

or, better, suggest a new feature to the plugin's maintainer.

See `:help a]`, `:help :s`, `:help :keeppattern`.